# How to upgrade from OAuth1 to OAuth2 for google marketplace apps?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I have a app in google marketplace with oauth1.I'm using oauth1 and openid.Now its asking to upgrade to oauth2.can anybody suggest any detail steps how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same line, but quit a head of gaining some knowledge on this
I found this is much mandatory or a first step to start with 
i hope this would help up some way a head like to me.

https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/ref/heads/master/README.md